# Convert notification to string

Tags: android

I am working on an application that receive system(all) notification
And store them in respective variables

I am facing problems in using `NotificationListnerService`

So please provide a code with complete explanation
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what kinda problem ?

Comment: Just made an app using NotificationListnerService which receives notification and stores them in a variable and broadcast them and receive them via broadcast receiver but the available code (searched on Google) is cumbersome which lacks description ;-;

Answer (score 0):

Is this the way u tried?

First you must declare your intent to receive notifications in your manifest, so that you can get the `android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
         android:label="@string/service_name"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Then create a `NotificationListenerService` class and override the `onNotificationPosted` function.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html
https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example/

Comment: Yup, but I want it to be more descriptive as am a beginner in android development and I don't know much

Comment: In MainActivity.Java a variable is declared  private NotificationReceiver nReceiver; but error occurred which says unable to resolve variable